# What exactly does CIDisplacementDistortion do?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I am fairly new to image manipulation and very new to Core Image.   I have been reading through the documentation for 4 or 5 days now and cannot seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I believe that the CIDisplacementDistortion filter may do what I'm attempting to accomplish (based purely on its name). I cannot, however, seem to find any details about what exactly it does other than to use a grayscale image to apply a texture to the image of interest.

Does anybody know **HOW** it accomplishes this?  Displacement implies that each pixel is offset by some vector (or probably more precisely is provided by a value at some vector offset).  A grayscale image is a scalar field.

Would I be correct in guessing that the vector field is based on the intensity gradient?

Thanks much,
mike

Comment: For reference, the (not terribly helpful) official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIDisplacementDistortion

Comment: Yep... that's all I could find.   The rather weak example doesn't help much.  Thanks for the pointer, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would be correct. The luminance of the input image is used to define a vector for the displacement. Normally, the luminance will be between 0 and 1. That will be multiplied by the input scale. It's not clear from the example where the direction of displacement comes from, so I would assume that it would be the direction of the gradient at any given point, since there's really no other way it could be calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the seconding vote on my guess.  I'm going to proceed down the path assuming this to be correct.   I'll have to do some playing around with the inputScale to get a feel for how to interpret its value.  I'll also have to integrate the desired offset (gradient) field to create the appropriate grayscale image.   I'll report back on the success/failure of this endeavor.